# continuing document flow after an auto height div

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with div positioning. i'm building an interface that somewhat resembles a table, but i'm doing it all with divs, and it's filled dynamically with php.

each entry is contained in a div with the class `.entry`. within that div are a bunch of smaller divs that change in height depending on what the content is from php.

between each entry I have a div called `.seperator` which is a black bar that seperates the entries from one another.

when i place a seperator after my auto filled `.entry` div, the seperator bar floats up to the top behind the `.entry` div. i'm not sure why this is happening. i'm guessing it's because there is no height set on the `.entry` div, but i can't set a height because i need it to expand based on the data.

so how can i get the entry to resize dynamically but still stay within the document flow, so i can continue to put other divs beneath it?

```css
.entry{
    width:100%;
    font-size:12px;
}
#seperator{
    height:10px;
    width:100%; 
    background-color:black;
}
```

and both of these are nested within my main container

```css
#mainContainer{
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    background-color:white;
    width:1000px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

So, if I set a height on the entries, then I get my separators right where I want them. My main issue I guess is that I don't know the height of the entries, because they're generated dynamically.

Comment: could you show the link or code?

Comment: What have you tried? What effect are you looking for? Do you want the `.separator` (correct spelling btw) to be as tall as the `.entry`? I'm not quite getting you so please elaborate.

Comment: no no, I want it to cascade down, like an entry, then a separator, then an entry, then a separator etc. right now the separators are floating up behind the entry, because it doesn't have a height set. but i can't set a height because i don't know it.

Comment: Please add the HTML aswell. Are there any other CSS that is involved, add them aswell.

Comment: Before I add all my HTML, I kind of revised my original question. How do I declare a height on a div where the content of the div is generated dynamically? I need the height so the document flows, but I can't set it because I need it to be auto...

Comment: All is not needed. I don't see why you will need to declare a height since for all I understand of this issue it should work right of the box in a browser. If a block (that contains the entry) has a following block (that contains the black background) the entry should push down the black block and not depend on any height. It should stretch. Therefor I need to see what is different in your page from what normally happens and why.

Comment: @Henrick thank you that's what I thought. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Turns out I had an element within the entry floated to the left. When I cleared the float, everything fell into place.

Comment: Floats. I had a hunch they were involved. Good thing you found it!

Comment: I always stick them in and forget to clear, and get extremely frustrated when I can't figure out why things are behaving strange.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to say what is happening without seeing the actual HTML code, but I would say that your problem is that the contents of the entries are floated and then the entry is not expanded to contain them.

Try using this:

```
.entry{

    overflow: hidden;

    width:100%;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Making the *overflow* hidden you force the entry to expand to the size of its inner elements, even if they are floated.